# In which Stack Exchange site should I ask about analyzing web page activity?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I understand Stack Overflow is not the correct place to ask my question, but I am uncertain which site should I ask about tools for completing a Web based task. My question is:

> What options are there when it comes to viewing traffic on Questions and Posts across Forums and websites? SE sites do a pretty good job of letting you know how much attention your question is getting, but I would like to find a way to monitor and graph the views on a specific webpage chronologically so I can draw conclusions such as "when is the best time to post for max attention", or "After what kinds of actions or edits will activity increase the most"? All the tools that I have looked at are specific to only sites that you are maintaining. What steps should be taken toward either building my own tool to do such a thing, or finding an application that produces similar output? (Any suggestions can help, from more ideas on specific keywords to google, to links of existing tools, to code)

Which Stack Exchange site would be appropriate to ask this kind of question, that most likely programmers would know the answer to, but is not necessarily directly related to code?

I can see this being applicable to Programmers, Stack Overflow, Web Applications, and maybe even Statistics with a stretch.

Comment: Not sure if you meant "Webmasters SE" or "Web Applications SE". We don't have "Web Developers SE". Feel free to edit to clarify if Webmasters isn't what you meant.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 4):

Nowhere in the current state would that be a constructive question. It leads to nothing more than pitching a tent for a quick line about a product or tool and they're off again.

That or it's not a real question, showing lack of prior research for any tool to play around in your hands with.

For a more constructive version you would come to the table and present a tool that you're currently using, but just not a total Zen master on. Now, with the tool in hand and a plate of asking about how to get your pants over a hurdle, you're in better business than the bureau.

Comment: Great input. I wasn't worrying about formating the question well until I knew WHERE to put it. I will revise this question to make it clearer. Where should a well prepared and researched question about tools go?

Comment: Depends on what your research is. If your conclusion is "I want some tool" or "I have a list. That all tools are not created equal. And here is my laundry, please wash it" type, they're similarly not going to fly. @joh

Comment: nice quips. it seems hard to form a good question.